# Can I still replay Desmond's Missions after completing the game?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

In the present hub, there's a computer to play again Desmond's Missions.

But in the ending of the game, an event makes that hub becomes inaccessible in the end-game (spoilers!).

So, is it possible to replay Desmond's missions after completing the main game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot play Desmond's missions after completing the main game. You can however start a new game and play the missions on there.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only replay them from outside the animus, and at the end of the game that option dissapears from the pause menu for reasons of ****SPOILERS****. However, what I did was I started a new save and did every mission but I didn't open the door at the end, so I had done all of the Desmond missions but the leave animus option was still there.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. We have a [special format](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) for spoilers o that you can include them in your answer without bothering those who don't want to see them. Otherwise, it's a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. I think that you ***can't***  replay those missions, because you're stuck in the Animus.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to replay missions after completing game from mission stats but I'm not sure if it changes your original score.

Use the pause menu and look for your mission stats and notice it offers replay for every memory.

I've done the cursed Lee chase several times and it seems I'm stuck with my original score.

The way I found to do this is: pause,open animus,click on leaderboards,open mission stats and you will see a replay option.

You all are correct that these memories do not include Desmond.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

> Desmond goes into another coma (I think) and gets trapped in the animus forever like 16 (I think) its like in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood,when after you complete the game you lose the option to log out of the animus.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot on the PC version either. Once the final mission starts, there is just no option for statistics, just:

- Resume
- Options (volume, blood, etc.)
- Controls (X, Y, etc.)
- Customize Controls
- Customize Boat Controls
- Quit